# php - withdraw exp from the user

Tags: php

I need a calculation to finish, since I already have the calculation to give the appropriate level according to EXP, now I need to remove this EXP, example:

If the user has 1050 of EXP, the calculation must remove all values equal to 100, which means that he withdraws the 1000 and leaves the 50.

My code is:

```
   $limit_exp = 100; 
   $player_exp = selectplayerexp($db);

   //this variable calculate the according lvl, ex: 1000/100 = lvl 10
   $levelup = (int) ($player_exp / $limit_exp);

   //this one have to withdraw exp equal to 100, ex 1150, stay with 50exp
   $withdraw = (int) (   ??????????????    );
```

Please, What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [modulo (`%`)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) operator for this. This will give you the remainder of a division.

If you want to find the amount remaining, it's:

```
$player_exp % $limit_exp
```

It looks like you're trying to find an amount to subtract from what you have stored in the database, so you can subtract that amount from the total.

```
$withdraw = $player_exp - $player_exp % $limit_exp;
```

There should be no need for an `(int)` cast on that calculation, as the `%` expression will evaluate to an integer.